# How can I make a shape from a slide appear in another slide using VBA for powerpoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'd like to make a shape from a slide 2 appear on a slide 1 on powerpoint using VBA, Do you know how can I do it?

PS: I actually tried to develop some codes but they didn't work at all...

Code I tried to develop but didn't work at all...

```
slide1(slide2.shapes("A").visible = msotrue)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy a shape from Slide 2 to Slide 1?

Comment: Welcome to SO. try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.copy) Is the shape complex like a map?

Comment: If a shape is on slide 1, it will only appear on that slide. You must either copy the shape to slide 2, or re-create it there with VBA.